# Need help to convert the bash code to python equivalent

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have this in my bash script

```
for FOLDERNAME in `\ls -1 /home/`
do
if [ ! -d /backups/home/${date} ]; then
mkdir /backups/home/${date}
chmod 777 /backups/home/${date}
/bin/chgrp ${FOLDERNAME} /backups/home/${FOLDERNAME}
usermod -a -G ${FOLDERNAME} john
fi
```

how can i convert that to python code

Comment: Step by step is the easiest way.

Comment: Show us what you've written thus far and any errors you are getting and we will help with that. We can't just 'do it for you'

Comment: i am reading the os module and i will post back when done . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most of it can be done using the ["os" module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) : I advise you to have a look at the doc of this module, try, and if you have issue, ask for relevant questions.

Answer (score 0):

While not being very familiar with Linux commands, this code should help you in attaining your final goal.

```
import shutil, datetime
shutil.copytree('/home/', '/backups/home/' + datetime.date.today().isoformat())
```